# how get the current value of input on knockout focusout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im basically new to knockout.js. I wanted to get the value of the input on focus out. The focus out event will trigger a function that would change some items on my observable array variable.

Here's the code:

```
<input placeholder="Enter a caption" type="text" data-bind="event:{focusout: $parent.modifyPhotoCaption(id, $(this).val())}" />
```

However, $(this).val() doesn't work, nor the this.val. I wanted to get the value of the current input immediately.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

I think I havent really gave a lot of details. The reason why I wanted to get the value immidiately is because there are a lot of input text:

```
<input placeholder="Enter a caption" type="text" data-bind="event:{focusout: $parent.modifyPhotoCaption(id, $(this).val())}" />
<input placeholder="Enter a caption" type="text" data-bind="event:{focusout: $parent.modifyPhotoCaption(id, $(this).val())}" />
<input placeholder="Enter a caption" type="text" data-bind="event:{focusout: $parent.modifyPhotoCaption(id, $(this).val())}" />
```

I don't know how to get the values via an array. And it seems that doing this is the fastest

Comment: I Would rather bind your input to an observable value and then subscribe to the observable.

Comment: One question: if you already use Knockout bindings - why don't you simply bind your photo caption and your input field to the same object/property in your viewmodel? Manually triggering the update of the caption seems completely unneccessary to me.

Comment: Show your complete viewModel.

Comment: @Comebal I Must agree with Alexander and ask for the complete viewModel. If yuo have alot of inputs you could define them as an observablearray and do a virtual foreach binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented on your question: Use an observable property and subscribe to it. Do whatever changes you need to do in the observablearray in the subscribe, unless the bound item is part of the observable array.

```
var VM = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.foo = ko.observable();

    self.foo.subscribe(function() {
       // do whatever needed.
       console.log(self.foo()); 
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```